# Practicamos hablando

Tags: gramática

> 1. Hicimos muy pocos ejercicios y casi nunca **practicamos hablando** en español.
> 2. Hicimos muy pocos ejercicios y casi nunca **practicamos hablar** en español.

Dice que "**practicamos hablando**" no está escrito correctamente pero "**practicamos hablar**" es correcto.
¿Por qué?

Comment: ¿Quién dice eso? Las dos son correctas, depende de lo que quieras decir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1.  casi nunca practicamos hablando en español.
2.  casi nunca practicamos hablar en español.
```

Como dice JoulSauron, ambas son correctas, pero significan cosas diferentes.

La primera (*hablando*) funciona como complemento circunstancial, responde a la pregunta *"¿**Cómo** practicamos?"*.  Expresiones funcionalmente equivalentes serían "mucho", "en la escuela", "con el maestro", "mirando TV".

La segunda (*hablar*) funciona como objeto del verbo (*practicar*), responde a la pregunta *"¿**Qué** practicamos?"*, y debe ser un "algo", un sustantivo o una expresión que funcione como sustantivo. Y, como apuntan otras respuetas, en español los verbos usados como sustantivos van en infinitivo. Expresiones equivalentes serían "practicamos leer", "practicamos gramática", etc.

Answer (score 3):

En español idiomático, para usar un verbo como si fuera un sustantivo, hay que usar el infinitivo.  No se permite usar el gerundio así, aunque sea en inglés posible, común y, a veces, la única manera idiomática.

Eso suponiendo que querías decir algo como "nunca praticamos el arte de hablar en español".  Si realmente querías decir algo como "nunca praticamos mientras hablábamos en español", lo que escribiste está bien.

---

In idiomatic Spanish, to use a verb as though it were a noun, you need to use the infinitive.  Contrast this with English, where it is possible and common to use the gerund.  Indeed, using the gerund sometimes is the only way to say something without sounding stilted.

I'm assuming, here, that you were trying to say something like "we never practiced the art of speaking Spanish."  If you were actually trying to say something like "we never practiced while speaking Spanish," then what you wrote is, as @JoulSauron says, fine.

Comment: Thanks Michael. How about if I want to say "...we rarely practice speaking Spanish". How to say it in Spanish?

Comment: "...practicamos poco/raramente/infrecuentemente/&c hablar español" should do the trick.  You can move the adverb around: to my ears (I'm not a native speaker, but have lived in Mexico City for over eight years), it sounds ok anywhere in that phrase except for directly after "hablar."

Answer (score 0):

Las dos frases son correctas, depende de lo que quieras decir.

> Si quieres mejorar el español, continúa practicando.
>
> Toca muy bien el piano, pero continúa practicando todos los días.

Por otro lado:

> Para aprender los verbos, practicamos hablando.

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta